# ¿Cómo mostrar cada 2 filas un registro MySQL en un SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla a la que quiero filtrar sus filas, pero con una condición: que me muestre cada 2 filas (2 es un ejemplo). Si tengo 10 filas debería mostrarme la primera, la tercera, la quinta, la séptima, etc. Según la imagen como haría para solo mostrar las filas que tienen la flecha roja.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Consulta...querés un filtro dinámico? Es decir que varie según la cantidad de filas? Por ejemplo si son 20 filas..el filtro es diferente a si son 50 o 10? Tu idea es mostrar siempre la misma cantidad de filas independiente de la cantidad total?

Comment: ¿Ninguna de las respuestas ha sido de ayuda o la correcta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta esto:

```
set @a = 0;
SELECT @a, tb_usuario_id FROM `scezf_k2_items` WHERE (@a := @a + 1) % 2 = 0
```

Básicamente se crea una variable para crear el avance por pasos. La condición:

```
(@a := @a + 1) % 2 = 0
```

obtiene el modulo de la fila actual, en este caso el modulo de `2`. Es decir, los múltiplos de `2`. Ese numero es sustituible por el numero deseado para obtener el salto entre filas.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta hacerlo así:

```
SELECT @row AS row, T.*
  FROM tabla AS T
  JOIN (SELECT @row:= 0) R
WHERE (@row:= @row+ 1)
HAVING (row % 3) = 0
```

Resultado:

```
-------------------
|row |id  |dato   |
|-----------------|
|3   |3   |dato3  |
|-----------------|
|6   |6   |dato6  |
|-----------------|
|9   |9   |dato9  |
|-----------------|
|12  |12  |dato12 |
-------------------
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/XWNJIF8116)

Explicación de la consulta:

- `@row AS row`: asignamos un alias a la variable `@row`
- `JOIN (SELECT @row:= 0) R`: nos permite inicializar la variable sin tener que usar el comando `SET`.
- `WHERE (@row:= @row+ 1)`: incrementamos el valor de la variable justo antes de evaluar el modulo (`%`)
- `HAVING (row % 3) = 0`: indicamos que queremos aquellos registros cuyo `row` modulo `3` sea igual a `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr lo que planteas debes construir un cursor para lograr listar todos los registros ya sea de 2 o más según que desees. Primero debes de hacer un count a tu tabla es decir la cantidad de registro almacenados y con ese resultado del count ir restando por la cantidad que desees, como dices de 2 en 2 y ese resultado debe de guardarlo en el curso.

Comment: ¿Y cómo sería el código? ¿Y en qué se diferenciaría de las respuestas ya publiadas?

Comment: En que las demás respuesta no son dinámicas.